# Do the Nine Realms correspond to Nine Planets?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-the-dark-world, thor

As described in Thor and Thor II, do the Nine Realms of Norse Mythology as shown in the movie (comics) correspond to Nine Planets?

I'm looking for MCU answers for in relation to Thor, and if possible real world answer for Norse Mythology relation.

Comment: Related over on SF&F - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/44857/how-are-the-nine-realms-situated-in-space

Comment: If you're talking about the 9 planets in our solar system, I doubt that they correspond to the 9 realms. As far as I can tell, they didn't know about Uranus, Neptune and Pluto, which would only leave 5 non-earth planets (Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn) or 6 if you count Earth.

Comment: Highly unlikely (for all previous reasons), though they do match up rather well.
Mercury-Nidavillir.
Venus-Muspelheim.
Earth-Midgard.
Mars-Helheim.
Jupiter-Vanaheim
Saturn-Asgard.
Uranus-Jotunheim.
Neptune-Alfenheim
Pluto-Svartleheim.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the MCU is concerned it seems as though the Nine Realms **does** correspond to nine planets.

Thor even drew a picture although he may have dumbed it down for us Midgardians:

[image]

From a [**Wikia**](http://marvel-cinematic-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Nine_Realms)

> The Nine Realms were the nine main worlds of the Universe, interconnected through the world tree, Yggdrasil.

---

For **much** more information and some extensive answers regarding the comics interpretation I'd recommend this Q&A over on Science Fiction & Fantasy Exhange

[**How are the Nine Realms situated in space?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/44857/how-are-the-nine-realms-situated-in-space)

Comment: "Which is of the Milky Way galaxy." - what is that even supposed to mean?

Comment: I'm just quoting the source I found.

Comment: If you can't explain what it means, why are you quoting it? Wikia pages aren't reputable sources at the best of times - how can we rely on it if it doesn't even make sense?

Comment: I have to concur with Paulie_D

Answer (score 1):

As to the Marvel Universe, anything is possible. From the standpoint of Norse Mythology, the answer it's highly unlikely.

Certainly the 9 realms represented 9 worlds, but the idea of a world being a planet in the modern sense isn't really accepted until Copernicus. (The word planet derives from the Ancient Greek [*planetes*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=planet) which means simply "wanderers". The pre-modern conceptions of them ranged from actual deities to vehicles of deities, but not other worlds.)

Copernicus published [On the Revolutions of the Celestial Spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_revolutionibus_orbium_coelestium) in 1543. By contrast, the sources for Norse mythology pre-date this by centuries—both the [Codex Regius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poetic_Edda) and the [Prose Edda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prose_Edda) were drafted in the 13th Century CE.

Comment: The question says nothing about them being the nine planets in our solar system... Only generally, nine planets.

Comment: @Catija Answer amended to reflect planets in general. :)